# How can I select the longest text from my mysql database?

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, sql-order-by

I do clustering for news articles. I classify a number of data into a number of clusters. what I want to do is to take one data from each cluster that has content with the longest text.

I have two table, i want to join that two tables and show only the record with the longest text.

my tables:

Table newscontent

```
news_id   title   content      category
   1      abcd    abcd            a
   2      abcd    abcdefg         a
   3      abcd    abcdefghij      a
   4      efgh    efgh            a
   5      efgh    efghijk         a
   6      efgh    efghijklmn      a
   7      ijkl    ijkl            b
   8      ijkl    ijklmn          b
```

Table newscluster

```
newscluster_id   news_id  category  cluster
      1             1        a        0
      2             2        a        0
      3             3        a        0
      4             4        a        1 
      5             5        a        1
      6             6        a        1
```

Desired output:

```
news_id    title    content    category   cluster
   3       abcd    abcdefghij     a         0
   6       efgh    efghijklmn     a         1
```

How can i do that?

Comment: What do you mean by "longest text record" ? is it based on `content` field

Comment: *Only **the record** ...*. If you only want one record, why does your desired output have 2 records?

Comment: Your recent update doesn't change the data or expected output.

Comment: one output (the longest text) per one cluster, so there are 2 output, one for cluster 0, and one more for cluster 1, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can accomplish what you want by using a series of joins.  However, I have the feeling that your schema is not completely normalized.

```
SELECT t2.news_id,
       t2.title,
       t2.content,
       t2.category,
       t1.cluster
FROM newscluster t1
INNER JOIN newscontent t2
    ON t1.news_id = t2.news_id
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT t1.cluster, MAX(CHAR_LENGTH(t2.content)) AS max_content_length
    FROM newscluster t1
    INNER JOIN newscontent t2
        ON t1.news_id = t2.news_id
    GROUP BY t1.cluster
) t3
    ON t1.cluster = t3.cluster AND
       CHAR_LENGTH(t2.content) = t3.max_content_length
-- WHERE t2.category = 'a'
```

Comment: Thank you, this code works fine. But how if i want to select only the 'a' category?

Comment: Then just add `WHERE t2.category = 'a'` to the end of my query.

Comment: Sorry I guess there is a bit problem. When i run this code the data that appears only 171, whereas there are 416 clusters, each cluster should show one of the longest text data, so there should be 416 datas displayed. True, or not?

Comment: Update your question clearly showing us what you really want here.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select * from (
    select a.*, cluster from newscontent a
    join newscluster b on a.news_id =b.news_id
    order by length(content) desc) x
group by cluster
```

Some people will complain, but if it works, it works!

Comment: He wants fields from `newscontent` and your query completely omits this table.

Comment: @tim oops. Copy pasted wrong table name. Should work now.

Comment: The update also has a problem because you are selecting non aggregate columns with `GROUP BY`.  This would not run on most other databases, and not even on all versions of MySQL.

Comment: @tim it won't run on *any* other dbs AFAIK, but this is s MySQL question. If will run on all versions, but versions 5.7.5 onwards have `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` true by default, so the DB would have to be specifically configured for this to work, but it would still work.

Comment: Hmm...it might run on certain forks of MySQL, e.g. MariaDB, SQLite, etc., but better not to rely on such quirks.